# Sharepoint Modal - pass values using options and read from server

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am using Sharepoint dialogs.

I have followed this article to pass values to the dialog:
http://online.appdev.com/edge/blogs/doug_ware/archive/2010/09/25/passing-values-from-a-list-custom-action-to-server-code.aspx

this suggests to use read values usingwindow.top.g_childDialog.get_args() & storing the value as JSON in a hidden field, so that they can than be read by server code.

I managed to make this work.

However my problem is that I need to use this value from the server side immediately and having to pass this value from the client to the server.

As a I work around, I am doing a __doPostBack to go back to the server (after setting the hidden field), & in the server code, I read the data from the input field.

However, there is clearly a performance issue here as I am doing an extra postback.

Is there a way to read the options immediately from the server rather than from Javascript.

I know that you can use the query string (rather than options) but I have a relatively large amount of data that I need to pass and I do not want to use query string.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create an "empty" `SP.UI.ModalDialog` by pointing the URL in the options to #. Then programmatically create a `form` with a hidden field in the dialog's `iframe`. And execute a post request on this form.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. But I did not really understand your approach. Let's say that my dialog points to http://mypage.aspx. Are you saying that instead of mypage, I point to a blank page that contains an iframe to mypage?

Comment: When using an URL in the dialog options the iFrame will be added by SharePoint. Using # as URL displays an "empty" iFrame... Then you create a html form inside the body of the iFrame. After that you post the inner html form to your "mypage.aspx". Let me know if you need an example.

Comment: Thanks again for the information. I did try to implement but I did not manage to fit  it all together. Basically I have a problem understanding how it would work together - the dialog, the iframe and my page. Could you kindly provide an example if possible. Thanks!